# Does ADF support full screen mode?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Does Azure data factory support full-screen mode so that we can have more space?
I didn't find any documentation about it.
It will definitely provide a better experience.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can toggle full screen mode here
[image]

Comment: I came to say F11 + that button!

Comment: You mean we should bind it with shortcut F11, right?

Comment: That would be a nice feature! But I said that because F11 is fullscreen on most browsers, so it hides tabs and url bars, while the button you signaled hides the blue bar on the adf interface. So with F11 and that button, you get the complete full screen. BTW I have no clue why you are being downvoted here ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I thought it was you :)

Comment: Not at all! Your answer was correct